# Cocoa: Which info.plist key handles application name displayed in Finder and Dock?

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization

I have specified three keys in my localized info.plists files: 
`CFBundleName`, `CFBundleDisplayName`, `CFBundleExecutable`, and localization of application name performed correctly in both application menu (the menu bar in top of the screen) and finder info window ("**Command + i**" action).

But I do not know how to localize application name in Finder file window and Dock. Could anyone tell me how to achieve that? Thank you at advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The key for my question IS `CFBundleDisplayName`. But why my configuration took no effect? Because I did not set it in the original **...info.plist** file.

After specifying CFBundleDisplayName in default info.plist file, app name localized successfuly.